# how to install GnuPG::Interface perl module on windows?

Tags: perl, cpan

When I try to do this : cpan install GnuPG::Interface
either on Strawberry or Activeperl ( windows ) I get this error : 
I use last perl version available 5.26.1.1

```
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.2304)
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.66)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20170821)
Configuring A/AL/ALEXMV/GnuPG-Interface-0.52.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
which gpg ... 'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
gpg (GnuPG) not found at Makefile.PL line 7.
 Warning: No success on command[C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=si
te]
   ALEXMV/GnuPG-Interface-0.52.tar.gz
   C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
```

Any tip ? Im actually trying to install Mail::GnuPG but GnuPG::Interface is required.
thank you

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but think you got a better chance by installing perl and GnuPG::Interface on http://cygwin.org or http://mingw.org The error message you got implies that it need the `which` and `gpg` commands.

Comment: I used cygwin and it compiled correctly. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This line in `Makefile.PL`](https://metacpan.org/source/ALEXMV/GnuPG-Interface-0.52/Makefile.PL#L6):

```
system("which", "gpg");
die "gpg (GnuPG) not found" if ( $? != 0 );
```

is attempting to check if `gpg` exists in your `%PATH%` but since you do not have the standard *nix utility `which`, it fails. You can install Perl's [App::pwhich](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::pwhich) and replace that line with `system("pwhich", "gpg");` if you want or, if you know that `gpg` is in your `%PATH%`, delete that line from `Makefile.PL` entirely.

Alternatively, you can install [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) which will provide both `which` and `gpg` along with `perl 5.24.1`.

If one were to rewrite this `Makefile.PL` from scratch, I would recommend using [File::Which](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Which) to check for all locations on your `%PATH%` where a `gpg` executable exists.